# How can I add a still image inside a video with avconv or opensource software

Tags: debian, image-manipulation, video-encoding, avconv

I would like to add a still image inside a **h264** video following an `in` and `out` point in time. I would like to use only opensource/free Linux/Debian packages.

I tried a lot of things with `avconv` like overlay filter and multiple inputs but not able to accomplish what am trying to do.

**EDIT :**

I've been sucessful with the MLT framework.
http://www.mltframework.org/bin/view/MLT/MltMelt